# Find if the file with specific name exists in the current working directory in python

Tags: python

How to check if a file with specific names exists in current working directory in python?
I tried following but gives error

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()).isfile('xyz.csv')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check whether a file exists without exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[os.path.exists(path)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um3du.png)

```
import os
os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), 'xyz.csv')
```